# Django field name length/convention

Tags: django, django-models

I am not sure if this is a bug, by design or if I have done something wrong. I have run into this on 1.6.2 and 1.6.4

I have some fields in my models like:

> my_custom_field = models.CharField()

In my forms.py, I have:

> def clean_my_custom_field():

It does not get called. There seems to be a problem with having more than one underscore in the field name. I have several that have 2 or 3 underscores in the name. I have changed one to use a single underscore and it worked.

I have started to look at shortening the names, but was wondering if anyone has come across this and has a work around/fix. Would be nice to keep the descriptive names.

Or is it in fact a bug?

**UPDATED:**

The form is setup fairly basic. One thing to note is that the long field name seems to work in the Admin, but not in the front end form.

```
class MyBaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"

    def clean_active_listing_expiry_date(self):
        print "You are HERE!"
        "Do something else here"
```

UPDATE:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ... other fields listed before and after of course.
    active_listing_expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='Active Expiry Date',
        help_text="Date format: YYYY-MM-DD",
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

UPDATE:

views.py

```
def residential_add(request, ptype='Residential', template_name='properties/add_residential.html'):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        property_form = ResidentialPropertyForm(request.POST)

        if property_form.is_valid():
            print "*" * 60
            print "FORM IS VALID"

    else:
        property_form = ResidentialPropertyForm()

    return render_to_response(
        template_name,
        {
            'property': property_form,
        },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Comment: Could you show how have you defined your form?

Comment: Do you mean by single my_custom_field and by double my__custom__field? The second one is wrong.

Comment: @JuanMiguelTaboada The format is as shown in the post above. Single underscore between words, but multiple words.

Comment: @alecxe Updated with the form.

Comment: @bmeyer71 as far as I understand, you should have a method called `clean_active_listing_expiry_date`, not just `active_listing_expiry_date`.

Comment: @alecxe Sorry copy paste mistake it does have clean in front. Updated post.

Comment: @bmeyer71 what if you, for the sake of testing, change `fields = "__all__"` to `fields = ['active_listing_expiry_date']`?

Comment: @alecxe Unfortunately that didn't make a difference.

Comment: @bmeyer71 ok, could you please show `MyModel` definition?

Comment: @alecxe updated post. It is a pretty basic model, just listing the fields.

Comment: Is it possible that your form doesn't require any data to be entered and you're submitting the same values that were passed in as initial? https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/forms/forms.py#L271

Comment: @schillingt That doesn't seem to be the issue. As I mentioned in the update, it works in the admin but not when entered through my frontend. They use the same form. Also, I've changed the field name to a single word and it works. No other changes.

Comment: @schillingt I would like to add to this as well. I have another field that was not set to blank=True & null=True and was getting the same problem until I renamed the field to a shorter name.

Comment: @bmeyer71 Can you add the code from your view?

Comment: @schillingt The views are still being developed, but I've posted what there is. Since it's not getting past the 'is_valid' portion I've not gone further.

Comment: What do you mean it's not betting past the ```is_valid()``` call? Is that returning False? If so, what are the errors in the form?

Comment: @schillingt No, it is calling the is_valid() since validation does happen, but it doesn't do the print statements afterwards because validation doesn't complete so it presents the form again. That part is working. The clean_(fieldname) part is not working, outside the admin.

Comment: @bmeyer71 The last thing I'd checked would be to make sure the field's clean method (not the form's clean) isn't raising a validation error since that gets called before the clean_custom_field method.

Comment: @schillingt If there is an error, that should be raised when using the Admin to fill out the form as well right?

Comment: Not quite. The POST in the request could potentially be different.

Comment: @schillingt I'm not sure I am following. For testing, I changed the field name to one word and ran the same tests. The clean_(fieldname) method ran in both cases. It is only when the field name is something like my_custom_field that the clean_my_custom_field method won't run outside the admin.

Comment: Yeah, I'm at a loss then. If you can reproduce this on a fresh project, it's worth submitting as a bug to https://code.djangoproject.com/newticket

Comment: @schillingt thanks for giving it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce the problem on a fresh install as suggested by @schillingt so I decided to start the form, view and validation code from scratch. Not sure what was missed the first time around, but at this point the issue seems to be resolved.

Thanks to those that offered up their help.